# Reload f imported with 'import foo as f'?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I reload the module when it is imported as
`import foo as f`?

Comment: `reload(f)` should work fine, what is the exact issue?

Comment: I was trying `import foo` and `reload foo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the built-in [`reload`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) function:

```
reload(f)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying `import foo` and `reload foo`.